# Pandas Columns to Flattened Dictionary (instead of list of dictionaries)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a DF that looks like this.
`df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'Value': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: np.nan}})`

|  | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2 | b |
| 2 | 3 | c |

I'd like to create a dictionary out of it.
So if I run `df.to_dict('records')`, it gives me

```
[{'Visual_ID': 1, 'Customer': 'a'},
 {'Visual_ID': 2, 'Customer': 'b'},
 {'Visual_ID': 3, 'Customer': 'c'}]
```

​However, what I want is the following.

```
{
    1: 'a',
    2: 'b',
    3: 'c'
}
```

All of the rows in the DF or unique, so it shouldn't run into same key names issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
d = dict(zip(df.ID, df.Value))
```